# How to change Fabric Twitter Title name when try to login

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric

[image]Hello any one know here how to change title name in fabric framework right now it's showing demo account name now want to show application name.

I want to change name Authorize created by Fabric for "APPNAME" on ios to use your account

Comment: You need to change your application name from twitter developer site : https://apps.twitter.com/ also check : https://docs.fabric.io/ios/fabric/manage-your-settings/app.html

Comment: i have tried but there is no section for this title

Comment: check the second link there is already manage your setting title

Answer (score 3):

You can change above from fabric.io.Follow the steps to change title name

1.Login to fabric.io and select the application.

2.Select twitter kit from leftside panel that looks like

[image]

3.You will see something like the image below
[image]

4.Click edit and set according to requirement.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i already logged in but there is not twitter icon is there in fabric.io in my account.  http://postimg.org/image/8bg684lbv/

Comment: how did you integrate twitter login to your app?...have you used fabric?...or something else

Comment: yes i have used fabric for twitter login functionality.

Comment: for selected app it shows the installed kits twitter,mapbox etc via fabric in the left panel as the image attached in answer.Please check if you are selecting app which has twitter login added via fabric.The + button is to add new kits.

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here. Do you have the correct init code in your Fabric init call? If so, try enabling debug mode, by adding: 

// Objective-C
[[Fabric sharedSDK] setDebug: YES];

// Swift
Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true

before your init call and see if that helps get the icon to show up in the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

I am also integrate twitter using fabric of following tutorial:

[**How to installed Fabric in XCode.**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-installed-fabric-in-xcode.html)

See its working :

[image]

Comment: i have follow same steps for integration fabric and twitter but not able to find   twitter installed app in fabric.io in my account.